# Java Multithreaded Caching with Single Updater Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, ehcache

I have a web service that has ~1k request threads running simultaneously on average. These threads access data from a cache (currently on ehcache.) When the entries in the cache expire, the thread that hits the expired entry tries getting the new value from the DB, while the other threads also trying to hit this entry block, i.e. I use the BlockingEhCache decorator. Instead of having the other threads waiting on the "fetching thread," I would like the other threads to use the "stale" value corresponding to the "missed" key. Is there any 3rd party developed ehcache decorators for this purpose? Do you know of any other caching solutions that have this behavior? Other suggestions?

Comment: What happens to the entries in the cache when they expire? Are they removed from the cache, or just flagged?

Comment: Good idea.  If an element is flagged as expired the value is returned and then a refresh is initiated.

Comment: Another option in to load a totally new and unused cache, then swap it with the old cache.

Comment: With ehcache the value in the cache gets evicted (i.e. cleared) when you try to access it, but ideally I would like it as it has been suggested, i.e. the expired value is kept around and returned to other threads until the new value overwrites it.

Comment: don't you think you are sending in stale data to that thread. If that doesn't bother you then why expire the cache in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know EHCache good enough to give specific recommendations for it to solve your problem, so I'll outline what I would do, without EHCache.

Let's assume all the threads are accessing this cache using a Service interface, called FooService, and a service bean called SimpleFooService. The service will have the methods required to get the data needed (which is also cached). This way you're hiding the fact that it's cached from from the frontend (http requests objects).

Instead of simply storing the data to be cached in a property in the service, we'll make a special object for it. Let's call it FooCacheManager. It will store the cache in a property in FooCacheManger (Let's say its of type Map). It will have getters to get the cache. It will also have a special method called reload(), which will load the data from the DB (by calling a service methods to get the data, or through the DAO), and replace the content of the cache (saved in a property).

The trick here is as follows:

1. Declare the cache property in FooCacheManger as [AtomicReference](http://cupi2.uniandes.edu.co/~cupi2/sitio/images/recursos/javadoc/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html) (new Object declared in Java 1.5). This guarantees thread safety when you read and also assign to it. Your read/write actions will never collide, or read half-written value to it.
2. The reload() will first load the data into a temporary map, and then when its finished it will assign the new map to the property saved in FooCacheManager. Since the property is AtomicReference, the assignment is atomic, thus it's basically swiping the map in an instant without any need for locking.
3. TTL implementation - Have FooCacheManager implement the QuartzJob interface, and making it effectively a quartz job. In the execute method of the job, have it run the reload(). In the Spring XML define this job to run every xx minutes (your TTL) which can also be defined in a property file if you use PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer.

This method is effective since the reading threads:

1. Don't block for read
2. Don't called isExpired() on every read, which is 1k / second.

Also the writing thread doesn't block when writing the data.

If this wasn't clear, I can add example code.

Answer (score 0):

Since ehcache removes stale data, a different approach can be to refresh data with a probability that increases as expiration time approaches, and is 0 if expiration time is "sufficiently" far.

So, if thread 1 needs some data element, it might refresh it, even though data is not old yet.
In the meantime, thread 2 needs same data, it ***might*** use the existing data (while refresh thread has not finished yet).  It is possible thread 2 might try to do a refresh too.

If you are working with references (the updater thread loads the object and then simply changes the reference in the cache), then no separate synchronization is required for get and set operations on the cache.